# What word (past tense verb) means that people are scared of the noun being affected by the verb?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm trying to write a single sentence to describe a whole story. There is mental illness and a woman is scared of the mentally ill man (this was in the 1950's) What word, similar to stigmatized, can I use in the following phrase: ... suffering of a mental illness in a world where it is misunderstood and ______.

Comment: *tabooed* perhaps.

Comment: Can you explain why you do not wish to use stigmatised? It is the word best fitted to the circumstances you describe, better than *despised*, *discriminated against*, *feared*, *misunderstood* and others.